# Counting the number of months from a column in a dataframe to each month in a sequence for multiple rows

Tags: r, for-loop

this is my first post so I do apologize if I am not specific enough.

I have a sequence of months and a data frame with approximately 100 rows, each with a unique identifier. Each identifier is associated with a start up date. I am trying to calculate the number of months since start up for each of these unique identifiers at each month in the sequence. I have tried unsuccessfully to write a for loop to accomplish this.

Example Below:

```
# Build Example Data Frame #
x_example <- c("A","B","C","D","E")
y_example <- c("2013-10","2013-10","2014-04","2015-06","2014-01")
x_name <- "ID"
y_name <- "StartUp"
df_example <- data.frame(x_example,y_example)
names(df_example) <- c(x_name,y_name)

# Create Sequence of Months, Format to match Data Frame, Reverse for the For Loop #
base.date <- as.Date(c("2015-11-1"))
Months <- seq.Date(from = base.date , to = Sys.Date(), by = "month")
Months.1 <- format(Months, "%Y-%m")
Months.2 <- rev(Months.1)

# Create For Loop #
require(zoo)
for(i in seq_along(Months.2))
{
  for(j in 1:length(summary(as.factor(df_example$ID), maxsum = 100000)))
  {
   Active.Months <- 12 * as.numeric((as.yearmon(Months.2 - i) - as.yearmon(df_example$StartUp)))
  }
}
```

The idea behind the for loop was that for every record in the Months.2 sequence, there would be a calculation of the number of months to that record (month date) from the Start Up month for each of the unique identifiers. However, this has been kicking back the error:

> Error in Months.2 - i : non-numeric argument to binary operator

I am not sure what the solution is, or if I am using the for loop properly for this.

Thanks in advance for any help with solving this problem!

Edit: This is what I am hoping my expected outcome would be (this is just a sample as there are more months in the sequence):

```
 ID Start Up Month 2015-11 2015-12 2015-12 2016-02 2016-03
1  A        2013-10      25      26      27      28      29
2  B        2013-10      25      26      27      28      29
3  C        2014-04      19      20      21      22      23
4  D        2015-06       5       6       7       8       9
5  E        2014-01      22      23      24      25      26
```

Comment: Can you post an example of what output you are expecting so that it is easier for people to answer your question correctly?

Comment: I added the expected output, sorry about that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is to first use `as.yearmon` from `zoo` package to convert the dates. Then simply we iterate over months and subtract from the ones in the `df_example`,

```
library(zoo)

df_example$StartUp <- as.Date(as.yearmon(df_example$StartUp))
Months.2 <- as.Date(as.yearmon(Months.2))

df <- as.data.frame(sapply(Months.2, function(i) 
                    round(abs(difftime(df_example$StartUp, i, units = 'days')/30))))
names(df) <- Months.2
cbind(df_example, df)

#  ID StartUp 2016-07 2016-06 2016-05 2016-04 2016-03 2016-02 2016-01 2015-12 2015-11
#1  A 2013-10      33      32      31      30      29      28      27      26      25
#2  B 2013-10      33      32      31      30      29      28      27      26      25
#3  C 2014-04      27      26      25      24      23      22      21      20      19
#4  D 2015-06      13      12      11      10       9       8       7       6       5
#5  E 2014-01      30      29      28      27      26      25      24      23      22
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x_example <- c("A","B","C","D","E")
y_example <- c("2013-10","2013-10","2014-04","2015-06","2014-01")
y_example <- paste(y_example,"-01",sep = "")

# past on the "-01" because I want the later function to work. 

x_name <- "ID"
y_name <- "StartUp"
df_example <- data.frame(x_example,y_example)
names(df_example) <- c(x_name,y_name)


base.date <- as.Date(c("2015-11-01"))
Months <- seq.Date(from = base.date , to = Sys.Date(), by = "month")
Months.1 <- format(Months, "%Y-%m-%d")
Months.2 <- rev(Months.1)

monnb <- function(d) { lt <- as.POSIXlt(as.Date(d, origin="1900-01-01")); lt$year*12 + lt$mon } 
mondf <- function(d1, d2) {monnb(d2) - monnb(d1)}

NumofMonths <- abs(mondf(df_example[,2],Sys.Date()))

n = max(NumofMonths)

# sequence along the number of months and get the month count. 

monthcount <- (t(sapply(NumofMonths, function(x) pmax(seq((x-n+1),x, +1), 0) )))
monthcount <- data.frame(monthcount[,-(1:24)])
names(monthcount) <- Months.1

finalDataFrame <- cbind.data.frame(df_example,monthcount)
```

Here is your final data frame which is the desired output you indicated:

```
  ID    StartUp 2015-11-01 2015-12-01 2016-01-01 2016-02-01 2016-03-01 2016-04-01 2016-05-01 2016-06-01 2016-07-01
1  A 2013-10-01         25         26         27         28         29         30         31         32         33
2  B 2013-10-01         25         26         27         28         29         30         31         32         33
3  C 2014-04-01         19         20         21         22         23         24         25         26         27
4  D 2015-06-01          5          6          7          8          9         10         11         12         13
5  E 2014-01-01         22         23         24         25         26         27         28         29         30
```

The overall idea is that we calculate the number of months and use the sequence function to create a counter of the number of months until we get the current month.

Comment: Thanks for putting this together, this really helps!

Comment: @DW1 if you think it is the best answer then please click the "check" mark